# How can I use a decorator on a pyqt signal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, decorator

I have a decorator that is supposed to try / except any method given to the wrapper so that it can log on the GUI any errors encountered in order to give the user a chance to understand what is going on if the application is not working

The decorator is used on multiple methods of different classes and encapsulates slots and is therefore declared outside of the classes ( outside the only class in this simplified example)

Currently the following code does not work as there is never the right amount of arguments given ( always one too many)

I tried different ways of writing the decorator but my understanding of them is limited and it turned out into a guesswork, witch also means that even if I stumbled onto the solution by chance I would not know why it works and not all of the previous errors

Here is a simplified code that illustrates my issue, there are different spin boxes that connect to different slots each taking a different amount of arguments and the same decorator is used on all of them

```
    import sys
    from functools import partial
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSpinBox, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QApplication
    
    
    def except_hook(cls, exception, error_traceback):
        sys.__excepthook__(cls, exception, error_traceback)
    
    
    def my_decorator(method_reference):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return method_reference(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                print("saved from " + str(e))
        return wrapper
    
    
    class Foo(QWidget):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Foo, self).__init__()
            layout = QHBoxLayout()
            sb1 = QSpinBox()
            sb2 = QSpinBox()
            sb3 = QSpinBox()
            sb1.valueChanged.connect(partial(self.__pressed, sb1))
            sb2.valueChanged.connect(partial(self.__pressed_two, sb2, "arg1"))
            sb3.valueChanged.connect(partial(self.__pressed_three, sb3, "arg1", "arg2"))
            layout.addWidget(sb1, 0)
            layout.addWidget(sb2, 1)
            layout.addWidget(sb3, 2)
            self.setLayout(layout)
    
        @my_decorator
        def __pressed(self, spin_box):
            print("spin box now has a value of " + str(spin_box.value))
    
        @my_decorator
        def __pressed_two(self, spin_box, arg1):
            print("spin box now has a value of " + str(spin_box.value))
            print("this is arg 1 : " + arg1)
    
        @my_decorator
        def __pressed_three(self, spin_box, arg1, arg2):
            print("spin box now has a value of " + str(spin_box.value))
            print("this is arg 1 : " + arg1)
            print("this is arg 2 : " + arg2)
    
    
    sys.excepthook = except_hook  # by default QT will hide all errors behind a code, this is used to expose the issue
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    foo = Foo()
    foo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Could it be possible to point out why my solution is not working? I did try to find examples and explanations and am successful in making decorators that would work for methods that are not used as pyqt slots but I cannot work this one out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue doesn't seem to be with your decorator, but rather with connecting a method to the `valueChanged` signal. Since this signal emits data (the new value being set), you need to add an additional argument to the `__pressed` method that represent this data.

This is a simplified version of your code - you can see that the exception is properly handled by the decorator when the value in the spinbox gets too high.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSpinBox, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QApplication
    
def my_decorator(method_reference):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return method_reference(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            print("saved from " + str(e))
    return wrapper


class Foo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Foo, self).__init__()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.spinbox = QSpinBox()
        self.spinbox.valueChanged.connect(self.pressed)
        layout.addWidget(self.spinbox)

    @my_decorator
    def pressed(self, new_value):
        print(f"spin box now has a value of {new_value}")
        if new_value > 5:
            raise ValueError(f"Value {new_value} is too high!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    foo = Foo()
    foo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now, in my experience with PyQt, you *don't always need* to add the extra argument representing the data being sent by the signal. But in this case I'm assuming it is (somehow) mandatory due to the wrapping of the slot method. People more experienced with the library are free to correct me :-)

Comment: Mmh, sorry but that's not a precise answer, since the OP is using partial. The issue is that partial appends any additional argument to the provided `args`, so the solution should be to either change the behavior of the wrapper, or always consider the default argument of theyour signal.

Comment: Ah you're right @musicamante, I missed the bit about the partial and additional arguments. I will say however that juggling partial functions, slots and decorators sounds like a recipe to a headache. Maybe OP can refactor his code and turn the arguments given to `partial` as attributes of `Foo`, so that my solution becomes more applicable.

Comment: The reason I am using partial is because in the original code the spinboxes are created inside loops ( a file is read to know what to create ). Lambdas where not possible as they were causing issues and ended up not being practical because of it. I may need to change my approach to the problem if the architecture is not good

Comment: In the end it turned out I did not understand that the spinbox was already sending a value through the signal thanks a lot

Comment: @jfaccioni I agree, that's a dangerous mix... a possibility could be to call the function *minus* the last argument, *as long* as it's known that the signal *always* has one and only one argument: `method_reference(*args[:-1])` (I've not tested it, but that should work). Alternatively, it could be used a lambda (without any argument) that actually calls partial: this would ensure that the partial will *never* receive the signal argument (since PyQt will not use it given the function signature), but this would also complicate things much, much more.

Comment: @MatthieuRaynauddeFitte most signal send at least one argument, especially when they are about some property change. Always check the documentation to ensure that you know the full signature: while PyQt allows connecting to functions that accept *less* arguments than what the signal provides (including *no* argument at all), it's good practice to be aware of them anyway.