# Fail to run pyqt5 app after compiling the code using cython

Tags: python, pyqt5, cython

Here is a simple PyQt5 application. There is a `QCheckBox` in it and I connected its `clicked` signal to `foo()` function. By clicking on this checkbox I pass two parameters to the `foo()` function and print those parameters to the console. It works fine however after I compile this code using cython compiler by clicking on this checkbox I get a `TypeError`.

main.py:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QCheckBox
from functools import partial
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.chb = QCheckBox(self)
        self.chb.setText('My CheckBox')
        self.chb.move(10, 10)
        self.chb.clicked.connect(
            partial(self.foo, 'para1', 'para2')
        )

    def foo(self, p1, p2):
        print(p1, p2)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.pyx", line 15, in main.MainWindow.foo
    def foo(self, p1, p2):
TypeError: foo() takes exactly 3 positional arguments (4 given)
```

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize("main.pyx"))
```

I'm using python 3.7 on a windows 10 machine.

Cython==0.29.24 and PyQt5==5.15.4

Comment: "I get a TypeError": **what** type error?

Comment: @musicamante I added the error.

Comment: Try to add a third argument to `foo` and print that too: is it `False`?

Comment: @musicamante No, its `True`. it prints out : `('para1', 'para2', True)`

Comment: Sorry, I obviously meant `True/False`.Please consider that signals almost always have arguments, and in [certain situations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68728433/) that argument is added anyway when using `partial`, even if apparently the connected function doesn't accept further arguments, so it's always good practice to check all signal arguments, and also ensure to know how the connected function works (in this case, partial, so please read its documentation carefully). Finally, consider that `clicked` is not the best choice for a QCheckBox, and you should prefer `toggled` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that when cythonized the default argument is sent, so a possible solution is to pass that argument to it:

```py
def foo(self, p1, p2, checked):
    print(p1, p2)
```

Another option is not to use functools.partial but rather nested functions:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.chb = QCheckBox(self)
        self.chb.setText("My CheckBox")
        self.chb.move(10, 10)
        self.chb.clicked.connect(self.foo('para1', 'para2'))

    def foo(self, p1, p2):
        def wrapper():
            print(p1, p2)

        return wrapper
```

Comment: I suspect (but not 100% sure) that the Cython 3alpha version will be better here since it improves introspection of functions, and I suspect that's what's going wrong here. I'd also recommend that OP doesn't use Cython at all - this doesn't look like the sort of problem that it accelerates